# Meaning of "to the right" of directrix (e.g. Theorem $13.17$ in Tom Apostol's Calculus vol. $1$)

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I'm reading section $13.19$ in Tom Apostol's Calculus vol. $1$, and there he defined that any point $X$ is in the negative half-plane iff $(X-P)N < 0$, where $P$ is any point on the directrix $L$, and $N$ is a vector normal to the directrix.

He then says that in figure $13.12$ (where you could imagine directrix $L$ to be the $y$ axis, and normal $N$ to point in the positive $x$ axis, pointing to the right), the choice of the normal vector $N$ dictates that points to the right of $L$ are in the positive half-plane and those to the left are in the negative half-plane.

How could one prove that?

I think I could prove it by splitting into cases, where in the first case the origin is left to the X, then at X, then between X and P...but it seems like there should be a simpler proof, and I just don't understand how to formally treat one vector being to the right (or left) of a line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general the normal vector $N$ points towards the positive half space.

---

In the book the author is defining  conics as curves in a plane defined by a line $L$, a focus $F$ and a positive constant $e$ called the eccentricity.

In the drawing the line $L$ is parallel to the $y$ axis. So it's not hard to see that this line $L$ separates the plane into two regions : the region to the right of $L$ and the region to the left of $L$.

Introduce a point $P \in L$ and a normal vector $N$ to $L$.

By definition we know that one of these regions is the positive half-space (and the other the negative half-space) but which is which ???

By definition the positive is half space is the set of points $M$ in the plane which verify

$$ (M-P) \cdot N \geq 0$$

(you should understand $M-P$ as the vector $\vec {PM}$ )while the negative half-space is the set of points $M$ in the plane which verify

$$ (M-P) \cdot N \leq 0$$

To find out all you need to do is take a point $M$ to the right of $L$ and look at the sign of $(M-P) \cdot  N$, if it is positive this means that the right side is the positive halfspace.

In our example it is clear by our choice of normal vector $N$ that there exists a point $M$ to the right of $L$ such that  $N = \vec{PM}$. For this point

$$ (M-P) \cdot N = \Vert N \Vert \geq 0$$

Hence the right side is the positive halfspace.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my doubt was what it means *mathematically* (e.g. without visualizing the vectors, but directly from their definition) for a point to be to the right of a line, so could you please expand on that part? The rest of your answer is clear...

Comment: I'm not sure. Maybe you can adopt the following definition " A point $P$ is to the right of $L$ if and only if $f(P)$ is to the right of the line $x = 0$ where $f$ is an isometry mapping the line $L$ to the line $x  = 0$. I suggest you take the isometry consisting of the translation of the line  to the origin and then rotation around the origin (take the rotation with the smallest angle).

Comment: Thanks! That seems to be a more advanced concept than what is expected from us to know by now, and I'm a bit surprised he took it for granted in the exercise $13.21.2$...Probably there he had in mind the normal vector pointing in the same direction as in figure $13.12$, as well as in exercise $13.21.1$.

Comment: In exercice 13.21.2 he says that the line is vertical. I suppose he is implicitly assuming that the line as equation $x = a$ and that the focus is on the line $x = a - d$. For $P$ to be on the left or on the right boils down to simply checking if $x_P< a$ or not